# AngularJS $formatter and $parser for input field

Tags: angularjs, parsing, formatter

Is there a possibility to also use `$parser` and `$formatter` for an input field and not only for a directive?

This is my input field (AngularJs DateTimePicker)

```
<input type="text"
 class="form-control date"
 name="date"                                
 data-ng-model="vmModal.account.creationDate"
 datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy"
 is-open="vmModal.openedDatePicker"
 close-text="schlie&szlig;en"
 current-text="heute"
 clear-text="l&ouml;schen"
 datepicker-options="{startingDay: 1}"
 placeholder="Datum">
```

**[EDIT]**
Actually I don't know what to do, I need the string representation of the date because I show it elsewhere in the application. The only possibility I know would be to have another field in my javascript object which represents a date object.

Comment: `$parser` and `$formatter` are parts of `NgModelController` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController), so how else would you like to access them if not in a directive that requires `ng-model` ?

Answer (score 0):

I may have miss-understood your problem, but from your EDIT, it seems that you need to display or use the date selected through the input in some other place. This is standard stuff to have one *model* and several *views*. In your case, you can just display `vmModal.account.creationDate` with a different format as the one used in the datepicker, using the angular `date` filter. 
E.g. when you select the following date in the datepicker: 25.12.2016

```
<em>{{vmModal.account.creationDate | date:'EEEE, dd MMMM yyyyy' }}</em>
```

shall display

> Sonntag, 25 Dezember 2016

See the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VIoeN0q8670ljOUxUbfC?p=preview) in action.

Note that you can specify alternate date formats for manual entry. In the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VIoeN0q8670ljOUxUbfC?p=preview) I added `alt-input-formats="['dd/MM/yy']"`. The user can now enter `25.12.2016` or `25/12/16`, both formatted dates will be parsed as date objects.